# Unity getComponent not updating correct value

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying to update a variable in a player movement prefab class. In my update function in a different script I set that player movement value to false. However in the update function of the player movement class, the player movement value is set to true when discovered through debugging.

Any help?

[image: different script]

Edit: I am trying to change the variable of a photon instantiated object. Maybe this is the problem?

[image: character movement]

DisableMove, is the value that remains false

Comment: The problem isn’t discernible in the posted code. You’d need to paste in a lot more of the relevant code (preferably not as images) for there to be a chance to identify it. In general, though, if there aren’t errors in the console it should be one of three things: the code changing it to true isn’t being executed (before you check it) OR it’s being changed back to false by something before you check it OR the bool you’re changing and the bool you’re checking aren’t actually the same variable for some reason (e.g. if you ended up working with two different instances of the class somehow).

Comment: 1. Did you check if `disableMove=true` code is reachable?
2. You mentioned that you use photon instantiated object. Do you test this code on the one machine or over the network?

Comment: Please include code as text, not as images.